# Error con subida de imagen desde celular PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, php7

tengo un problema para subir una imágenes al servidor desde celular, y es raro porque puedo subir archivos PDF pero no imágenes, eso solo desde el celular ya que desde pc me sube sin problemas las imágenes y los pdf.

```
<input type="file" id="apc_adjunto[]" name="apc_adjunto[]" accept=".jpg,application/pdf" multiple>

  $contarAPC = count($_FILES['apc_adjunto']['name']);
  $extensiones_apc = "";
  for($i=0;$i<$contarAPC;$i++){
    $extension_apc = pathinfo($_FILES['apc_adjunto']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $extensiones_apc .= $extension_apc.",";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['apc_adjunto']['tmp_name'][$i],'DATA/'.$idCliente.'/apc_'.$idCotizacion.'_'.$i.'.'.$extension_apc);
  }
```

Comment: Es imposible responder algo a esta pregunta. ¿Hay algún mensaje de error? ¿Qué dicen los logs del servidor? ¿Qué dice el log del dispositivo? ¿Ocurre con Android y con iOS por igual? ¿Qué tamaño tienen las imágenes?. Creo que debieras leer [ask] y luego [edit] tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienen el problema de subir imágenes/archivos deben aumentar el tamaño de subida en php.ini

upload_max_filesize = 10M

post_max_size = 10M

y sí, las imágenes que tenía en el pc eran menores a 2MB que es el por defecto.